# Project Euler Task 17

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

So I am currently going through Project Euler I am on problem 17. The problem is

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?

Personally I though the problem would be pretty straight forward. Now, I know that my code isn't the most optimal and I know that I can find solutions all over the web. But I am merely looking for what is wrong with my code. The answer I get is 21224, while the correct answer is 21124.

```
  int Sum = 0;
    int Hundred;
    int Ten;
    int One;
    void Count()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Hundred = i;
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Ten = j;
                for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    One = k;
                    switch(i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Sum += 3;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Sum += 3;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Sum += 5;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Sum += 4;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Sum += 4;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Sum += 3;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Sum += 5;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Sum += 5;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            Sum += 4;
                            Sum += 7;
                            Tens();
                            break;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        Sum += 11 + 99*9*3; //Taking into account the "one thousand" and the "and"s
        label1.Text = Sum.ToString();
    }
    void Tens()
    {
        switch (Ten)
        {
            case 0:
                Ones();
                break;
            case 1:
                switch (One)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Sum += 3;
                        
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Sum += 6;
                        
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Sum += 6;
                        
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Sum += 8;
                        
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Sum += 8;
                        
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Sum += 7;
                        
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Sum += 7;
                        
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Sum += 9;
                        
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Sum += 8;
                        
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Sum += 8;

                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Sum += 6;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 3:
                Sum += 6;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 4:
                Sum += 6;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 5:
                Sum += 5;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 6:
                Sum += 5;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 7:
                Sum += 7;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 8:
                Sum += 6;
                Ones();
                break;
            case 9:
                Sum += 6;
                Ones();
                break;
        }
    }
    
    void Ones()
    {
        switch(One)
        {
            case 0:
                
                break;
            case 1:
                Sum += 3;
                
                break;
            case 2:
                Sum += 3;
                
                break;
            case 3:
                Sum += 5;
                
                break;
            case 4:
                Sum += 4;
                
                break;
            case 5:
                Sum += 4;
                
                break;
            case 6:
                Sum += 3;
                
                break;
            case 7:
                Sum += 5;

                break;
            case 8:
                Sum += 5;
                
                break;
            case 9:
                Sum += 4;
                
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"forty" is 5 letters, but in your `Tens` method you have

```
 case 4:
     Sum += 6;
     Ones();
     break;
```

and "forty" would show up 100 times so there's the difference.

Personally I think it would be better to have arrays that map the digit to the number of letters instead of using a bunch of switch cases.  That's how I did it and I just double checked my values against yours to find the error.  Something like

```
var onesDigit = new[] { 0, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4 };
var teens = new[] { 3, 6, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 8 };
var tensDigit = new[] { 0, 0, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6 };
```

And the `onesDigit` can be reused with the hundreds + the 7 for the word "hundred".